# Set voting in Openstack Zuul based on branch

Tags: zuul-ci

In a legacy project we use Zuul and we need to base the zuul variable 'voting' on which branch has triggered the job.

`- name: ^job_name$
   branch: <?>
   voting: <true or false or ?>`

Observe we use an older version of Zuul (2.x).

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do conditions for `voting` but you can split your jobs in two categories, ones that are voting and ones that are not voting.

A common approach is to have one job per branch.